# Update access db from textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

im new in c# and asp.net world!
I have  a problem.
In access db i have 2 table ( book, loan ) with a referential integrity constraint ( book.ID = loan.ID ).

In my project i have some textbox and when i change a value of textbox i must update the tables.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cod = Request["cod"];

    //Componiamo la stringa di interrogazione al database relativa alla tabella b_prestiti
    qry = "UPDATE b_libri SET codice='" + TextBox1.Text + "' WHERE codice='" + cod + "'";
    string qry2 = "SELECT codice_libro FROM b_prestiti WHERE codice_libro='" + cod + "'";
    string qry3 = "UPDATE b_prestiti SET codice_libro='"+ TextBox1.Text + "' WHERE codice_libro='" + cod + "'";
    string qry4 = "UPDATE b_libri SET titolo='" + TextBox2.Text + "' WHERE codice='" + cod + "'";
    string qry5 = "UPDATE b_libri SET autore='" + TextBox3.Text + "' WHERE codice='" + cod + "'";
    string qry6 = "UPDATE b_libri SET editore='" + TextBox4.Text + "' WHERE codice='" + cod + "'";

    //Creiamo gli oggetti di tipo OleDbConnection
    //passando la stringa di connessione al costruttore
    conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    OleDbConnection conn3 = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    //Inizializziamo gli oggetti di tipo OleDbCommand
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand();
    OleDbCommand cmd3 = conn3.CreateCommand();

    OleDbDataReader reader2 = null;
    //OleDbDataReader reader3 = null;

    //Apriamo la connessione
    conn.Open();
    conn2.Open(); 
    conn3.Open();
   /* 
    cmd2.CommandText = qry2;
    reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();*/

    if (MessageBox.Show("Sei sicuro di voler aggiornare questo libro?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (!first_titolo.Equals(TextBox2.Text) || !first_autore.Equals(TextBox3.Text) || !first_editore.Equals(TextBox4.Text))
            {
              /*  while (reader2.Read())
                {
                    if (reader2["codice_libro"] != "")
                    {
                        if (MessageBox.Show("VINCOLI REFERENZIALI! Vuoi aggiornare comunque?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            cmd3.CommandText = qry3;
                            reader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                            reader3.Close();

                            MessageBox.Show("Vincolo Aggiornato!");
                        }
                        else Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                    }

                }*/
                /*cmd.CommandText = qry;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Close();*/
                MessageBox.Show("aggiornato!");
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("no");
          /* 

            if (first_titolo != TextBox2.Text)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = qry4;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Aggiornato!");
            }

            if (first_autore != TextBox3.Text)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = qry5;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Aggiornato!");
            }

            if (first_editore != TextBox4.Text)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = qry6;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Aggiornato!");
            }

        */

        }
        //else Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");


//    reader2.Close();

    //Chiudiamo la connessione
    conn.Close();
    conn2.Close();
    conn3.Close();

}
```

I don't know how do it! Help me please!

Comment: Please remove unnecessary, commented out code

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand non-english for me but I suggest this as one improvement you can make:

```
   string qry = "UPDATE b_libri "
                   "SET titolo='" + TextBox2.Text + "', "
                   "SET autore='" + TextBox3.Text + "', "
                   "SET editore='"+ TextBox4.Text + "' " 
                " WHERE codice='" + cod + "'";
```

To help with the other stuff, please post your table creation and constraint creation code for us.  Then we will be able to help with those issues.

Comment: You only need one comment.  Please change the original question with your updated info.  Don't post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have experience with OLE connections, but in principle it is:

```
OleDBCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand( qry3 );

if ( cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 )
{
  // at least one row updated
  //everything is ok
}
else
{
  something went wrong
}
```

Use ExecuteNonQuery, it will execute a sql statement that is not a SELECT and will return the rows affected.

Also, there is no need for multiple connections, one should be enough, you can execute multiple commands on one connection.

Also repsect Hogan's answer!
Edit: As per Hogan's suggestion changed the comparision and the remark

hth

Mario

Comment: hmmm... doesn't ExecuteNonQuery() return the number of rows affected.  How is 1 always the correct answer?  Not sure this is a great template.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved about the different values of textbox.
Now i have 2 tables and i should check, when i change the value of Codice(Id), if there's a 
referential integrity constraint.

```
// Aggiorna
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cod = Request["cod"];

        //Componiamo la stringa di interrogazione al database relativa alla tabella b_prestiti
        qry = "UPDATE b_libri SET codice='" + TextBox1.Text + "' WHERE codice='" + cod + "'";
        string qry2 = "SELECT codice_libro FROM b_prestiti WHERE codice_libro='" + cod + "'";
        string qry3 = "UPDATE b_prestiti SET codice_libro='" + TextBox1.Text + "' WHERE codice_libro='" + cod + "'";
        string qry4 = "UPDATE b_libri SET titolo='" + TextBox2.Text + "' WHERE codice='" + cod + "'";
        string qry5 = "UPDATE b_libri SET autore='" + TextBox3.Text + "' WHERE codice='" + cod + "'";
        string qry6 = "UPDATE b_libri SET editore='" + TextBox4.Text + "' WHERE codice='" + cod + "'";

        //Creiamo gli oggetti di tipo OleDbConnection
        //passando la stringa di connessione al costruttore
        conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        OleDbConnection conn3 = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        //Inizializziamo gli oggetti di tipo OleDbCommand
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        OleDbCommand cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand();
        OleDbCommand cmd3 = conn3.CreateCommand();

        OleDbDataReader reader2 = null;
        OleDbDataReader reader3 = null;

        //Apriamo la connessione
        conn.Open();
        conn2.Open();
        conn3.Open();

        cmd2.CommandText = qry2;
        reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

        if (changed)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Sei sicuro di voler aggiornare questo libro?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (first_titolo != TextBox2.Text)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = qry4;
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Titolo Aggiornato!");
                }

                if (first_autore != TextBox3.Text)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = qry5;
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Autore Aggiornato!");
                }

                if (first_editore != TextBox4.Text)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = qry6;
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Editore Aggiornato!");
                }
                if (first_codice != TextBox1.Text)
                {
                    while (reader2.Read())
                    {
                       if (reader2["codice_libro"] != "")
                       {
                            if (MessageBox.Show("VINCOLI REFERENZIALI! Vuoi aggiornare comunque?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {

                                //reader3.Close();
                                cmd.CommandText = qry;
                                cmd3.CommandText = qry3;
                                reader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                               // reader.Close();
                                MessageBox.Show("Vincolo Aggiornato!");
                            }
                            else Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                       }
                       else 
                       {
                            cmd3.CommandText = qry3;
                            reader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                           reader3.Close();
                            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                        }
                    }

                    cmd.CommandText = qry;
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Codice Aggiornato!");
                    reader.Close();
                  //  reader3.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                    conn2.Close();
                    conn3.Close();
                    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                }
            }
            else Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

The problem is only when (fist_codice != Textbox1.Text). first_codice is the value of the textbox at first; Textbox1.Text is the actual value in the textbox1.
Thanks

Comment: This is not helpful.  If you want to change your question please do so -- adding an answer is the wrong way to use this site.  Change the original question.  ALSO include the SQL that defines your tables so we can help explain the problem you are having.  Without that there is no way to know what is going on.  The C# is useless to an SQL problem.